# URL Rewrite Stops Button Event from firing

Tags: asp.net, .net, webforms, web-config, postback

I have a webform `default.aspx` that inherits from a master page.

In the master page is a small form with a button that posts back.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    page content here

    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Call Me Back" />
</form>
```

Code Behind:

```
Private Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
     'post the data and redirect
End Sub
```

This works fine, until I add a rewrite into the web.config (re-writes `/default.aspx` to just `/`):

```
 <rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Default Document" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*?)/?default\.aspx$" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}/" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

How when I click the button, I get a postback, but the actual button event does not fire. I set a breakpoint on the event handler and it is not hit. Other pages inheriting from from the same master page work fine still.

If I rem out the rewrite the default page fires the button handler.

How can I ensure the button event fires using the re-write

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a fix for this which is to set the action value of the form tag.

I don't know why this fixes it though so if anyone can shed light on this then it would be helpful.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" action="/">

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add to page or master page that:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {       
            form1.Action = Request.RawUrl;        
        }
```